# Как лучше сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее: "победа В конкурсе" или "НА конкурсе"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Победа В конкурсе" - правильный вариант (ср.: успех в чем?; победа В соревнованиях; победа В сражении; победа В состязании). Возможет и вариант "победа НА ...", но только если речь идет о спортивных соревнованиях на какой-то плоской поверхности: победа на татами, победа на ринге, победа на шахматной доске.